# How can I avoid using of FINAL? (java)

Tags: java

I've got the next error: `Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method.`

I don't want to use a FINAL ArrayList, because I have to set modify some things.

```
for (int i = 0; i < verOrd.size()-1; i++)
{
    final int p = i;
    instruccion  = new JLabel("Instrucción de Orden "+verOrd.get(i).getNumOrden());
    statusIns.add(no);
    statusIns.add(ok);
    ventana.add(instruccion);
    ventana.add(no);
    ventana.add(ok);
    ventana.add(sig2);

    int a = 0;

    sig2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            if (ok.isSelected())

            {
                verOrd.get(p).setStatus("Finalizada");

            }                                   
        }

    });
}
for (int i = 0; i < verOrd.size()-1; i++)
{
    final int p = i;

    instruccion  = new JLabel("Instrucción de Orden "+verOrd.get(i).getNumOrden());
    statusIns.add(no);
    statusIns.add(ok);
    ventana.add(instruccion);
    ventana.add(no);
    ventana.add(ok);
    ventana.add(sig2);

    int a = 0;  

    sig2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            if (ok.isSelected())

            {
                verOrd.get(p).setStatus("Finalizada");

            }                                   
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: declare the `ArrayList` outside all the methods, directly inside the `class`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make an arrayList "final" and also continue to add/remove things in that arrayList.

Only thing you can't do, is assign that arrayList variable to something else.

Example:

```
final ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
// This is allowed:
list1.add(new Object());
// But this is not:
list1 = some_other_list;
```

Comment: Ok, but can I do this?

list1.get(1).setThing("Now have this text");

Comment: yes. you could do that too.   As long as you don't assign list1  to something  else, you can do anything to list1.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to encapsulate the variable (by defining a getter and setter). This is the OOP approach

Answer (score 0):

You could create the arraylist as a variable in the class For eg.,

```
Class Foo{

private ArrayList<type> list;

public Foo(){
list = new ArrayList<>(); 
 }

//Now you can use the list in your methods without making it final
}
```